# How I can get Vue component data while using script setup

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I need to rewrite
this code

```
export default Vue.extend<Props>({
  functional: true,
  render(h, { props, slots, data }) {
    const { href, external, target, type, button } = props;
    const slot = slots().default;
    console.log(data);
    ....
```

to Vue 3 Composition script setup,
So I managed to get

```
<script setup lang="ts">
 import {h, useSlots} from 'vue';
 const props = defineProps<Props>();
 const slots = useSlots();
 ...
```

But how I can get **data**  ?
from this part ->  render(h, { props, slots, **data** }) {

data should contain domProps if have such.. etc

*console.log(data);*

```
{
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  attrs: {
    target: '_self',
    href: 'https://example.com',
    button: true
  },
  class: [
    'X-button',
    {
      'X-button--': false,
      'X-button--size-auto': true
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does this `data` come from? Are not you declaring your own data section in the component?

Comment: `setup` has no data. In fairness, it's a replacement for `data`. Most importantly, it runs before `data` is setup in Composition API (should you use both `data` and `setup` functions in a single component). There's no way to access `data` in setup, even if you use both. If you expect to see there some reactive refs, you need to use [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) and run your code in `onMounted()`

Answer (score 0):

If you still need this,

`useSlots().default()` returns the data for the slots, including the DOM props.